# VBA Filter function throws 'Runtime error 13: type mismatch' error on an array created from a range

Tags: arrays, vba, filter, type-mismatch

I'm trying to search for a substring within an array using the filter function and then creating a new array of strings which include that substring. When I try, I get a type mismatch runtime error 13 message.  I've read that filter can only be used on a 1-dimensional array and that populating an array with a range automatically creates a 2-dimensional array, but I thought I'd read I could get around this problem if I transposed the array when creating it.  I think I might be wrong about that as it still doesn't seem to work for me.

Before the bug strikes, the headerTitles array is populated with the following strings:

- vaccination_date
- year
- month
- day
- site
- dose
- vaccine
- vaccination_setting

This is all using Excel 2010.

Thanks for any help.

```
Sub dateInHeaderTitle()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    Dim headerTitles As Variant
    Dim dateTitles As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)



    With ws
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        headerTitles = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Lastcol)).Value2)
    End With


    
    
    dateTitles = Filter(headerTitles, "date", , vbTextCompare)
    

    Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect from the `Filter` function, in this context?

Comment: In this case, I'd want it just to return the single element 'vaccination_date'.  In other examples, however, there'd be more headings with the suffix '_date'

Comment: Then, the 1D array starting from a column range needs a second `Application.Transpose`. Look to my answer and to the way of testing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to obtain a 1D array, starting from a column range, you should use:

```
headerTitles = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(1, lastCol)).Value2))`
Debug.Print Join(headerTitles, "|") 'just to see it...
```